# Twilio Video JWT token make error in api login

Tags: twilio

Hello want create Twilio video Token I have install library  Twilio token is generating but my API login stuck giving me error(status 500) kindly help me. on the local both things working (login API test in post man) but when project on live server it was giving error.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do this in a PHP application, is that right? Can you share the code you are using? Have you ensured you installed the dependencies on your live server?

Answer (score 0):

This Was PHP version Issue of my server. Server have old version